# Can I rebind mouse buttons to keys?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am having a problem with the controls in Diablo 3. Basically, it puts my abilities on my mouse, but I want to use my mouse for movement only.

But at the same time, if I move abilities away from my mouse, I run out of room, because there is only room for numberkeys 1 - 4.

If there any way I can use the mouse *only* for movement, and activate my abilities with 1-6 instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, you cannot remap the mouse buttons away from the primary/secondary skills.  You *can* use **Elective Mode** (`Options` > `Gameplay` > Check `Elective Mode`) to move any skills (including primary/secondary) to keys 1-4, but you can only remap those keys.  Therefore, if you want to avoid using the mouse for skills, you will be limited to only 4 skills.

Answer (score 1):

I used autohotkey to bind key buttons to keys. Here's my script:

```
q::MouseClick
+q::MouseClick
w::MouseClick, right
+w::MouseClick, right
```