# Is there a way to hotkey builds?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to quickly switch between attack types?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63704/is-it-possible-to-quickly-switch-between-attack-types)

Is there an easy way to switch my hotkey layout ? Like if I wanted to setup a hotbar for single target and a hotbar for aoe. I want to switch rapidly depending on what I'm fighting. It sucks running into a giant room of mobs and having to stop and switch to aoe attacks while all my buddies are causing havoc already.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. More to the point, because of the 5 second cool down on changing skills, it's *impreactical by design*.

Skill selection is an important part of strategy in D3. You should design your load out so that you have the tools necessary to handle any situation you feel you need to. This is reinforced at end game, where you are *actively penalized* for changing out your skills in between fights.

One thing you *can* do is turn on 'Elective Mode' in the games settings in order to give yourself more flexibility in the assignment of hotkeys.

Comment: Isn't turning "on" elective mode what you mean? I can't check right now.

Comment: You're actively penalized for changing out skills *between* fights?  Do what now?

Comment: Why is this impractical by design?  You can swap skills anywhere and the cooldown delay when switching between an AoE setup and single-target is trivial compared to the time spent repicking a half dozen skills and their runes.

Comment: Shinrai - you lose the Nephalem Valor buff when changing skills http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Nephalem_Valor