# Can I change the Diablo 3 controls to be more like the Heroes of the Storm controls?

Tags: diablo-iii, heroes-of-the-storm

I would like to make Diablo 3's gameplay more like Heroes of the Storm's which I am more comfortable with.  It looks like rebinding most of the spells to different buttons would accomplish this mostly, but is there a way to change Diablo 3's "move and attack" to HotS's "move and begin auto attacking nearest enemy" system?

Comment: It's old, but related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/57048/336

Comment: Auto-attack is not a thing in Diablo for several reasons. First, there is no "attack" ability (well, there is, but no one in their right mind will use it, as there are plenty of zero-cost abilities for any character class). Second, auto-attack with any sensible weapon that 5 of 6 classes would hold is a melee strike, and having your character automatically endanger themselves does not seem much of a help to the player. And the last point is that in Diablo, you are supposed to constantly move, rotate your skills and choose your targets - the combat is much faster than in HotS.

Comment: I think its worth adding that previous RPGs used the scheme of "move and attack", but as the genre progressed, there became a greater focus on controling your character, and deliberately attacking. May not make sense on PC, but on console it adds to immersion. Your deliberetly swinging your axe, diving out of the way of an on coming fireball, casting that ability or spell. You find the scheme you describe more native to RTS, these days, where heroes of the storm is a "battle arena", which is the spawn chils of having created an RPG within an RTS. In my experience, of course.

Comment: @Timelord64 Diablo, and more broadly its derivatives in the genre of "hack and slash," have always used the "direct" control scheme in which the camera follows the player character and units don't have to be selected. You might be thinking of CRPGs such as Baldur's Gate and Neverwinter Nights, Those games revolve around planning and are much more slow-paced and are even designed to allow the player to pause any time they want to consider their next action. In these games there is a layer of detachment because it focuses heavily on playing the role of a different character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such system that you are able to take advantage of in Diablo 3. If you click on an enemy that is out of range of your attack, you will walk to them and attack them once.

The closest you are going to get to an "auto attack" is by clicking on an enemy and holding down the button/key, this will make your character attack that enemy until you let go of said button/key or until you run out of energy for the attack.

Alternatively you can hold down the Shift key (by default) to make your character stand in place and then press and hold the button/key of the attack you wish to use.

Comment: What about rebinding the keys? You've missed that in your answer :)

Comment: I didn't put it in as OP states that it is possible and would accomplish their goal, therefore not needed :)

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought that providing that information to users who do not know how would help make your answer more complete and helpful to users who are looking to achieve a HOTS type setup and arrive here.

Comment: Haha I am going to I just haven't had the time to get screenshots and edit up a final answer. I just wrote a short answer for op for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**. In Diablo 3, you're in more direct control of your character, while in HoTS and other MOBA's, you control them more like a unit in a strategy game. You can, however, rebind the skill keys to QWER if you prefer, (if so, make sure to rebind the potion key etc. to something else)

However, I have a suggestion for you:

Play the game for a while. Most likely, you'll find that you get used to the control system and why it's well suited to this type of game. Moving from one game to another usually requires a few hours to get used to the control scheme. This is totally normal and something gamers do quite often.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718652-diablo-iii/67164736) auto attacks aren't present in this game. However, rebinding your keys is possible. LINK: [Can I rebind mouse buttons to keys?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57048/can-i-rebind-mouse-buttons-to-keys)